# JSON.stringify not working for mongoose object in NodeJs

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I got an error while console **mongoose** object. 
Here is my code:-

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Yea! we are connected.');
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(mongoose));
```

Here is Error Message:-

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. Why do you want to convert the mongoose object to JSON anyways?

Comment: What are you trying to do? That's wrong you are trying to stringify the module object.

Comment: I just want to see what data are exits in mongoose object. If i use `console.log(mongoose)` i got result but not appropriates.@qqilihq,@Michelem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try the **[`util.inspect(object)`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options)** method which returns a string representation of an object:

```
var util = require('util');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Yea! we are connected.');
});
console.log(util.inspect(mongoose, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

Comment: I can see whole mongoose attributes and members with naked eye.Thanks @chridam.

Answer (score 2):

inside mongoose module have this logic

```
Mongoose.prototype.Mongoose = Mongoose;
```

It makes Circular structure ( object self-reference) . You cant default stringify an Circular Object. If you want to use `JSON.stringify` add your custom logic handle

```
JSON.stringify(obj,function(k,v){ //logic})
```